# ReferenceError: message is not defined, how to solve?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm learning to code on discord.js so i may have gotten some things wrong, feel free to correct me if you find any issues. Right now this is the error I'm facing : ReferenceError: message is not defined

Here is the code :

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
});

const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.client) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping'){
            message.channel.send('pong!');
    } else if (command == 'joe'){
            message.channel.send('mama ;)');
    } else if (command == 'deez'){
            message.channel.send('NUTS!!');
    } else if (command == 'ur'){
            message.channel.send('mama');
    } else if (command === 'kick'){
            client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'ban'){
            client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args);
    }
});


client.login('token')
```

Comment: Please reset your token as you have leaked it. People can control your bot with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works for me when I run your code. The reason you get the error might be the fact that message is deprecated in Discord v13 as seen here [Updating from v12 to v13](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guild-nsfw). But that wouldn't raise an error and would just show that `(node:30426) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead`

Change your event in `client.on('message')` to `client.on('messageCreate')` and see if it works. It would help a lot more if you could post the whole error message here

Comment: Hello, i have already tried changing message to messageCreate without any success. I tried to run it again so i could post the error message but nothing shows up anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing shows up? Is it like that there is nothing coming in the console or is there an error?

Comment: no error shows up and the bot isn't responding to commands

Comment: Is the `console.log('The bot is online!')` line coming in the console?

Comment: Yeah, but that's the only thing

Comment: In the line where you write `if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.client) return;`, change `message.author.client` to `message.author.bot` and see if it works!

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much